# Rabl caching wrong number of argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4, rabl

I am trying to enable caching on my Ruby 2.1.1/Rails4.1.0 app for the Rabl json template. it is

in my config/development.rb

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

in my app/controllers/phones_controllers.rb

```
def show
  @phone = Phone.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    # format.json { render json: @phone }
    format.json
  end
end
```

finally, the app/views/phones/show.json.rabl

```
object @phone
cache @phone
attributes :area, :number, :country, :id, :created_at, :updated_at, :phoneable_id, :phoneable_type
```

And the error I am getting is

```
  Rendered phones/show.json.rabl (2.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms

ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments (4 for 1):
  rabl (0.9.3) lib/rabl/digestor.rb:8:in `digest'
  rabl (0.9.3) lib/rabl/engine.rb:294:in `cache_key_with_digest'
  rabl (0.9.3) lib/rabl/engine.rb:279:in `cache_results'
  rabl (0.9.3) lib/rabl/engine.rb:39:in `render'
  app/views/phones/show.json.rabl:2:in `_app_views_phones_show_json_rabl__914081420294741706_70254824188740'
```

I spent a day on looking for more info about caching with Rabl but with very little result, can anyone point me to the right direction as to where to look or have experience with this?

Thank you!

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: No, I still am not able to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this error is a result of a change in cache digest handling in Rails 4.1.0. RABL has been updated to fix this (https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/pull/540), but the fix is only available as a prerelease at the moment:

```
gem install rabl --pre
```